# How to extract items out of a QueryDict which contains keys with more than one value?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have this ***QueryDict***:

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&c=3')
```

I need a piece of code which returns this result:

```
{ u'a': [u'1',u'2'], u'c': u'3'}
```

I should inform you that `dict(q.iterlists())` returns this:

```
{ u'a': [u'1', u'2'], u'c': [u'3']}
```

Regards,

Comment: Can you explain why you want the first case? what's the problem with `'c': [u'3']` if you have trouble in getting the desire result by indexing you can simply do `q['c'][0]`.

Comment: Because it has just one value, I want not to be a list. @Kasramvd

Comment: you are getting a list after iteration, then after that just pluck if you want data like q['c']

Comment: @MahyarDamavand If this question is solved then please consider accepting an answer (not necessarily mine).

Comment: I will do tomorrow @timgeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter answer:

```
{
   key:val if len(val)>1 else val[0]
   for key,val in q.lists()
}
```

Comment: sorry for my mistake. Unicode output is not necessary to change. I corrected my question. thank you for your answer. @timgeb

Answer (score 1):

If you want the querydict to be converted into json,

You could do something like this,

```
>>> from django.http import QueryDict
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&c=3')
>>> q
<QueryDict: {'c': ['3'], 'a': ['1', '2']}>
```

I actually did it like this,

```
>>> string_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(dict(q)))
>>> string_dict
{'c': ['3'], 'a': ['1', '2']}

>>> for item in string_dict:
...     if len(string_dict[item]) == 1:
...         string_dict[item] = string_dict[item][0]
... 
>>> string_dict
{'c': '3', 'a': ['1', '2']}
```

Comment: sorry for my mistake. Unicode output is not necessary to change. I corrected my question. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that you *should* not want this.

Anyway, this comprehension gets rid of the unicode strings (again, you should not want this) and single value lists:

```
d = { 'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': [u'3']}
>>> {k:(map(str, v) if len(v) > 1 else str(v[0])) for k,v in d.items()}
{'a': ['1', '2'], 'c': '3'}
```

Comment: sorry for my mistake. Unicode output is not necessary to change. I corrected my question. thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MahyarDamavand no problem, make sure to double check your input and expected result in the future in order to avoid downvotes and get better answers.